# Why does #[derive(Show)] not work anymore?

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

With today's Rust nightly the following code doesn't compile anymore:

```
#[derive(Show)]
enum S {
    A,
    B
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", S::A);
}
```

Instead it gives me the following error message:

```
error: the trait `core::fmt::String` is not implemented for the type `S`
```

Is there a way to get the old behaviour? Surely it can't be required to implement this by hand for each type.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The old `Show` trait was split into `Display` and `Debug`.

- `Display` is designed for user-facing output, and uses the blank/default format specifier (e.g. `{}`, `{:.10}` `{foo:}` are all using `Display`)
- `Debug` is designed for debugging/internal output and uses the `?` format specifier (e.g. `{:?}`, `{:.10?}`, `{foo:?}` are all using `Debug`)

Hence, to use the implementation created by `#[derive(Debug)]` one should write `println!("{:?}", ...)`, instead of the old `println!("{}", ...)`.

Only `Debug` can be `#[derive]`d since output like `Foo { x: 1, y: 2 }` is unlikely to be the correct user-facing output, for most situations (I'm sure it is for some, but then the programmer can write the implementation of `Display` to do that themselves, or even call directly into the `#[derive]`d `Debug` implementation).

This was originally described in [RFC 504](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0504-show-stabilization.md) and there is ongoing discussion in [RFC 565](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0565-show-string-guidelines.md), making the guidelines stated above more concrete.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is to use `{:?}` instead of `{}` in `format!`.